# mpmovieplayer not setting background in ios6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

This code does not set the background view of a `MPMoviePlayerController` in iOS6 but works perfectly in iOS7.

```
UIView *patternView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
patternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
imgView.image=imgBackGround;
[patternView addSubview:imgView];
[self.moviePlayer.backgroundView addSubview:patternView];
```

What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ultimately setting the view with background color red.If you only wants set the background color,then instead of taking any view and adding it, set its MPMoviePlayerController view's  background color directly.

`[self.moviePlayer.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Comment: there is a imageView as well.which is the most important.any ideas?

Comment: you can add image  using following line  [self.moviePlayer.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"your image"]];

Comment: Yes you can use above method...But colorWithPatterImage method consumes memory...so keep a check on it !